# Audi A4 B5 (1995) climate control/heater/blower problem

Tags: audi, heat, a4, climate-control

The climate control was nuts all the time since I bought the car few years ago. I have the air conditioning liquid filled. The mechanics said, the pipes are all in good shape, but something is wrong, go check elsewhere, like electrics or stuff.

I checked the pipe leading to the interior, it is really cool, on the side where the glove box is. When you press the (*) snowflake on the climate control you can hear and feel the compressor kick in.

But the thing is, you can only feel a tiny little bit cooler air coming out when you set the temp at higher than 25-26°C. Seems like if the air is not mixing properly or something. If you set it lower temp or "LOW" - get ready for the hellish hot airflow. It's like some sensor or similar kind of thing is messed up and I don't know what. It can even randomly switch from blowing cooler air to hot air and turning off the compressor. I kind of suspect my climate control unit to be the culprit, but I'm no auto or electronics specialist. How can I troubleshoot? what steps can I take? what should I check?

### Update

By the way I checked and re-soldered the joints shown in this article. These were causing some issues for me too.

Comment: I would suggest the issue is either the blend door actuator or the controller itself. I don't know how you can directly troubleshoot either of these. Maybe someone has an A4 Service manual and can lead a step-by-step for you to diagnose.

Answer (score 1):

An Audi scanner, VCDS from Ross-Tech.com, will show up any electronic faults on your AirCon. Time and time again though, the symptoms you describe can be put down to the AirCon thermostat.

Comment: Yeah, I'll have to take a look at the thermostat. Only if I knew where it is

Comment: If I said AirCon thermostat around the workshop they know that I mean 'AirCon Resistor Pack'. It acts as a thermostst.